# Assign output from a loop to a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

this might be quiet a strange question but...

I have 3 vectors:

```
myseq=seq(8,22,1) 
myseqema3=seq(3,4,1)
myseqema15=seq(10,20,1)
```

And I want to assign the results to my list:

```
SLResultsloop=vector(mode="list")
```

With this loop:

```
for (i in myseq){
  for(j in myseqema3){
    for( k in myseqema15){
  SLResultsloop[[i-7]]= StopLoss(data=mydata,n=i,EMA3=j,EMA15=k)
  names(SLResultsloop[[i-7]])=rep(paste("RSI=",i,"EMA3=",j,"EMA15=",k,sep="|"),
  length=length(SLResultsloop[[i-7]]))

}
}
}
```

The problem is as follows: `the loop above overrides the list elements. So does any one have a clever solution about how to assign the loopresults to unique list elements (without overriding previous results)?`

One solution could be to assign the output to different lists but it is a bit of an ugly solution...

Best Regards

Comment: `mylist[[i]][[j]][[k]]`? That would give you a nested list. The question is if that's the optimal structure for your data ...

Comment: @Roland Thanks, but do you have a better solution as well?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the loops entirely by using `expand.grid` and `apply` (or something similar):

```
g <-
expand.grid(myseq = myseq,
            myseqema3 = myseqema3,
            myseqema15 = myseqema15)

apply(g, 1, function(a) {
    StopLoss(data=mydata, n=a[1], EMA3=a[2], EMA15=a[3])

})
```

You can then build your names for each element of the return value from `apply` using something like:

```
paste("RSI=",g[,1], "EMA3=", g[,2],"EMA15=", g[,3], sep="|")
```

Comment: That is a great solution indeed! Didn't think about `expand.grid`. Thanks!